# Uniform Probability Density Function over the interval [5,15], find E(r) and V(r)

Tags: probability

I am attempting the following maths question,

[Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rafw.png)

I am able to work out the expected value however when I attempt to calculate the variance I get two different values.

For $E(r)$ I gained a value of $10$.

But when using the following formula for calculating V(r);

[Given formula for V(r)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvmQZ.png)

Which was given to me from my lecture notes. Where $N = 2$, and P$(X_n) = 1/2$.
That gives an answer of $25$ which doesn't match any of the solutions in the question.

However I looked on Khan Academy and found the following equation for $V(r)$;

[Khan Academy $V(r)$ equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/py6PS.png)

This one provided me with an answer of $50!$ Which does match answer A.

So my question is basically is that correct to use the second equation and if so, how do I know what situation to use which equation for $V(r)$?

Comment: And it is not a continuous random variable in the interval [5, 15] ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $r$ has [uniform distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(continuous)) over interval $[5,15]$ then it has a PDF that takes value $\frac1{10}$ on $[5,15]$ and takes value $0$ on $\mathbb R\setminus[5,15]$.

If $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is a Borel-measurable function then:$$\mathbb Ef(r)=\frac1{10}\int_5^{15}f(r)dr$$

This calculation can be done for e.g. the functions prescribed by $x\mapsto x$ and $x\mapsto x^2$ resulting in the values $\mathbb Er$ and $\mathbb Er^2$.

Further we have equality: $$\mathsf{Var}(r)=\mathbb E(r-\mathbb Er)^2=\mathbb Er^2-(\mathbb Er)^2$$enabling you to find the variance.

The formulas mentioned in your question do not apply on uniform distribution over an interval and cannot be used.

They deal with discrete uniform distribution or sample variance.

Comment: Ok thanks for pointing out the right equation. I'm just a bit confused when I use it in my example, I get the value of 25 for Var(r)? Can you please tell me if I am doing something wrong? using E(x) = 10 I get E(x^2) = 125 and [E(r)]^2 = 100 putting that into the equation I get 25?

Comment: $\mathbb{E}r^{2}=\frac{1}{10}\int_{5}^{15}r^{2}dr=\frac{1}{10}\left[\frac{1}{3}r^{3}\right]_{5}^{15}=\frac{325}{3}$
so that $\mathsf{Var}\left(r\right)=\frac{325}{3}-10^{2}=\frac{25}{3}$.

Comment: Brilliant @drhab thanks for the help!